# Draggable legend with multiple axes problem

Tags: python, qt4, matplotlib, legend

I’m wondering if anyone has a solution for a problem I’m having when using a draggable legend in conjunction with multiple axes.

I’m using gridspec and figure (matplotlib 1.0.1, qt4 backend) to create 2 axes – no pyplot. When the legend is dragged from one axes to the other and released, its draggability ceases to work.

If a portion of the legend is outside the boundaries of the axis, the legend can be picked up by clicking on that portion, but not if the mouse is clicked on any area of the legend inside the axis.

I tried [Adam Fraser’s original code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539477/how-to-draggable-legend-in-matplotlib) but the legend would slip under the 2nd axes in my app.

My app is really quite large - too large to show here, so to illustrate the problem, I’ve modded some code from the [Matplotlib Legend Guide](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/legend_guide.html) (uses pyplot) as follows:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

subplot(211)
plot([1,2,3], label="test1")
plot([3,2,1], label="test2")
leg=legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3,
           ncol=2, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.)
leg.draggable(state=True, use_blit=True)

subplot(223)
plot([1,2,3], label="test1")
plot([3,2,1], label="test2")
leg=legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
leg.draggable(state=True, use_blit=True)

show()
```

It produces a plot with a couple of axes and two legends.

Run the code and drag the legends around to see the effect (if you don't have any problems, it must be something I ate and I apologize).

I suspect a solution may be fairly low level, but who knows, maybe it’s a simple fix?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: +1 description is correct. No answer.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the problem. The part of the legend that enters the alien figure becomes unclickable, as if the figure would be catching the mouse position events and not resending them to other handlers.

The minimal code that reproduces the problem (to experiment with ipython -pylab) is:

```
In [16]: f211 = plt.subplot(211)
In [17]: f212 = plt.subplot(212)
In [18]: p1 = plot([1,2], label="test1")
In [20]: leg = legend(loc=(0.5,0.5))
In [21]: d = leg.draggable(state=True, use_blit=True)
```