# bounding box problems saving to pdf

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, bounding-box

I need to save matplotlib figures to pdf. I am following the instructions on the [Matplotlib howto](http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html), except that instead of displaying results, I'm saving it to pdf. Strangely, the **pdf canvas is not affected by the canvas resize**. Conversely, **saving to png works properly** with the enlarged canvas.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(range(10))
ax.set_yticks((2,5,7))
labels = ax.set_yticklabels(('really, really, really', 'long', 'labels'))

def on_draw(event):
    bboxes = []
    for label in labels:
        bbox = label.get_window_extent()
        # the figure transform goes from relative coords->pixels and we
        # want the inverse of that
        bboxi = bbox.inverse_transformed(fig.transFigure)
        bboxes.append(bboxi)

    # this is the bbox that bounds all the bboxes, again in relative
    # figure coords
    bbox = mtransforms.Bbox.union(bboxes)
    if fig.subplotpars.left < bbox.width:
        # we need to move it over
        fig.subplots_adjust(left=1.1*bbox.width) # pad a little
        fig.canvas.draw()
    return False

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', on_draw)

plt.savefig("test.pdf", format="pdf")
```

[screen capture of pdf image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ7cW.png)

**UPDATE**

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

does it for title and axis ticks, but **ignores the legend** if it is placed outside the frame, as in the figure below. Notice that I placed the legend to the right of the figure.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
p1, = plt.plot(range(10))
p2, = plt.plot(range(10,0,-1))
ax.set_yticks((2,5,7))
plt.labels = ax.set_yticklabels(('really, really, really', 'long', 'labels'))
plt.legend([p2, p1], ["line with a loong label", "line with an even longer label, dude!"],\
           loc="center left", bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("test.pdf", format="pdf")
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15882249/matplotlib-aligning-y-ticks-to-the-left/15883858#15883858

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769870/matplotlib-wxpython-not-sizing-correctly-with-legend/18771068#18771068

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible hack is by replacing `plt.tight_layout()` with

```
plt.tight_layout(rect = [0, 0, 0.4, 1])
```

but that is not very nice. What works for me is using the argument `bbox_inches`:

```
plt.savefig("test.pdf", format="pdf", bbox_inches = 'tight')
```

Comment: The down side of `bbox_inches='tight'` is that you lose control of how big the final figure is.  That can be very important if you are trying to match the font size of your label and the text you are embedding the figure in.

Comment: @tcaswell good point. It is a caveat, but it doesn't invalidate the approach for most cases.

Answer (score -1):

Use can try this example and solve your problem.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
sin, cos = np.sin, np.cos

fig = plt.figure(frameon = False)
fig.set_size_inches(5, 8)
ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0., 0., 1., 1.], )
ax.set_axis_off()
fig.add_axes(ax)

x = np.linspace(-4, 4, 20)
y = np.linspace(-4, 4, 20)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
deg = np.arctan(Y**3-3*Y-X)
plt.quiver(X, Y, cos(deg), sin(deg), pivot = 'tail', units = 'dots', color = 'red', )
plt.savefig('/tmp/test.png', dpi = 200)
```

You can make the resultant image 1000x1600 pixels by setting the figure to be 5x8 inches

```
fig.set_size_inches(5, 8)
and saving with DPI = 200:

plt.savefig('/tmp/test.png', dpi = 200)
The code to remove the border was taken from here.

(The image posted above is not to scale since 1000x1600 is rather large).
```

Comment: The issue is not related to definition or saving to png. The issue is saving to __pdf__.