# draw plot with lots of text outside of it (matplotlib)

Tags: text, matplotlib

I have 2 points (a vector of size 8) and 3 different bitwise operation (And, OR, XOR) I mapped  each point and the result of bitwise operations on the 2D plot. I want to show each points real data itself and the result of operation beside my plot (right of the plot or above the plot (wherever is possible or it's better)) so later when I want to analysis the result I can read data value easily. right now my image is like this, and you can see the legend is cut off and I have no place outside of plot to write anything:

[image]

The text I want to show outside of my plot:

```
P1  P2  And Or  Xor     
0   1   0   1   1   
0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   
1   1   1   1   0   
1   1   1   1   0   
1   1   1   1   0   
1   1   1   1   0
```

The code I am using :

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
fig = pl.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
            
ax.plot(p1x, p1y, 'bx', label='Point 1', alpha=.55, markersize=30)
ax.plot(p2x, p2y, 'r+', label='Point 2', alpha=.55, markersize=30)
ax.plot(Andx, Andy, 'go', label='AND', alpha=.45, markersize=10) 
ax.plot(Orx, Ory, 'y<', label='OR', alpha=.45, markersize=10) 
ax.plot(Xorx, Xory, 'ks',  label='XOR', alpha=.45, markersize=10) 
ax.set_title('Bitwise Operation')
ax.set_xlabel('axis X')
ax.set_ylabel('axis Y')
ax.axis([-0.05, 1.05, -0.05, 1.05])
pl.legend(loc='lower left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 0), borderaxespad=0)
pl.show()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [add_axes](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html) to directly control the size and location of your axes and then use [text](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text) to add the text you want. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
fig = pl.figure()

ax =  fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4])

ax.plot(.1, .2, 'bx', label='Point 1', alpha=.55, markersize=30)
ax.plot(.2, .1, 'r+', label='Point 2', alpha=.55, markersize=30)
ax.plot(.3, .2, 'go', label='AND', alpha=.45, markersize=10) 
ax.plot(.1, .3, 'y<', label='OR', alpha=.45, markersize=10) 
ax.plot(.1, .2, 'ks',  label='XOR', alpha=.45, markersize=10) 
ax.set_title('Bitwise Operation')
ax.set_xlabel('axis X')
ax.set_ylabel('axis Y')
ax.axis([-0.05, 1.05, -0.05, 1.05])
pl.legend(loc='lower left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 0), borderaxespad=0)

data = ('P1  P2  And Or  Xor \n'
'0   1   0   1   1   \n'
'0   0   0   0   0   \n'
'0   0   0   0   0   \n'
'0   0   0   0   0   \n'
'1   1   1   1   0   \n'
'1   1   1   1   0   \n'
'1   1   1   1   0   \n'
'1   1   1   1   0   \n')

pl.text(1.75,0,data)
pl.show()
```

[image: plot with text outside of axis]

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769870/matplotlib-wxpython-not-sizing-correctly-with-legend/18771068#18771068 for some code that will auto-resize everything to fit

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to display certain extra data (parameters of the graph) in a text box, something similar to 'Text outside area' in [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/add-text-to-specific-points-on-graph.html). After some trial and errors, I stumbled upon this nicely written answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439132/3278350).

The Postprocessing part of the answer is really helpful.
`plt.subplots_adjust` gives the programmer a better control than the `plt.tight_layout`