# Additional information in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can we had special data next to a matplotlib figure
For example

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.legend()
plt.title()
plt.annotate()
```

Is there a way to put a box next the plot with additionnal data (I mean real textual comments ,....)

[image]

Comment: look at plt.text()

Comment: Not sufficient, I added a picture to explain my goal

Comment: It look like that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899009/draw-plot-with-lots-of-text-outside-of-it-matplotlib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use matplotlib's `text` function.

```
#data is your normal string variable only.
data = ( 'CPK = \n'
'Cp = \n'
... # Rest of your text 
)
plt.text(1.20,0,data)
```

The syntax is `plt.text(x_co-ordinate,y_co-ordinate,string_to_print)`. The figure is **`([0-1],[0-1])`**

Comment: yes, thanks. Just put what I finally did. Is ([0-1],[0,1]) the general system coordinate for figure ? I made a quick calculation to be 10% far from the plot (see answer below)

Comment: If you really need a lot of info, `table` can also be useful, although a bit more work: 
http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/table_demo.html

Answer (score 0):

Finally it works like this for me :

```
dict = OrderedDict()
dict['key1'] = stuff
dict['keyn'] = stuff
statdesc = '\n'.join(['%s : %s' % (key, value) for (key, value) in dic.items()])
plt.text(xmax+.1*(xmax-xmin), 0, statdesc)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Spandan's answer above, I would suggest to look at the Postprocessing part of the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439132/3278350).

The same `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust` and `matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout` functions can be used with text as well.