# Why all words in my legend's title are all joint?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

Is there other way to make legend's title in bold? Why all the words are joint?
[image]

Here my code:

```
    myLegend=plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.2, 1., .102), prop ={'size':10}, loc=10, ncol=4,
                title=r'$\bf{TOTAL ACCURACY AND PER STAGE - RANDOM FOREST}$')

    myLegend.get_title().set_fontsize('24')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a draggable legend in matplotlib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539477/how-to-create-a-draggable-legend-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Thanks, I will check the link. Anyway... do you know why all the words are all joint in the legend's title?

Comment: I don't know the right words, but it seems you are using latex-rendering and in some latex-subsets, whitespaces are omitted. Usually (but also try my later links) you would use ```TOTAL~ACCURARY``` where the tilde marks a whitespace. If i'm right, you could also check out [this](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_119.html) and [this](http://texblog.org/2014/04/09/whitespace-in-math-mode/).

Comment: Thanks Sascha. I tried it, but it did not work. I used instead: \enspace

Comment: you passed the title in a mathtext, which has no spaces. Remove the `$`'s

Comment: I removed $\bf{}$ and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1:

```
    myLegend=plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.2, 1., .102), prop ={'size':10}, loc=10, ncol=4,
                title=r'$\bf{TOTAL\enspace ACCURACY\enspace AND\enspace PER\enspace STAGE\enspace-\enspace RANDOM\enspace FOREST}$')
```

Answer 2:

```
    myLegend=plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.2, 1., .102), prop ={'size':10}, loc=10, ncol=4,
                title=r'TOTAL ACCURACY AND PER STAGE-RANDOM FOREST')
```

[image]